# System.Diagnostics.Trace remove default Trace

Tags: c#, dll, trace

I'm developping an API which implement Tracing (log file) by usin System.Diagnostics.Trace.

Everything is working correctly except that i'm using external dlls which automatically append useless information in my log file (Deserializing, serializing, etc...). As a result  my log file become stodgy.

the component who's writing Trace is a static class and i did not found any way to disable Traces from this provider. For information this static class comes from Microsoft SCCM SDK (Microsoft.ConfigurationManagement.ApplicationManagement.Serialization.SccmSerializer).

Is it possible to disable tracing from external dlls ??

by advance thank you.

Comment: Have you tryed to SourceFilter  ?